# How to perform inference in a simple mediation analysis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, bootstrap, mediation

I am running a very simple version of a mediation analysis with five variables, $y, x, t, z1, z2$. It's simple in that I am only including the mediated effect.

I first run $y = x + t + e1$. Next, I run $t = z1 + z2$.

Assume I obtain coefficients $\beta_x, \beta_t, \delta_{z1}, \delta_{z2}$ as coefficients. The coefficient for the mediated effect for $z1$, for example, is $\beta_t \times \delta_{z1}$.

My question is, how do I derive the correct standard error for this coefficient to perform hypothesis tests, calculate confidence intervals? Do I need bootstrapping for this? I am using a textbook that suggests that the correct standard error for the mediated effect is $s_{FIRST} = \sqrt{\hat a ^2 s_{\hat b}^2 + \hat b s_{\hat a}^2}$ (McKinnon - Intro to Statistical Mediation Analysis), but online sources seem to suggest that bootstrapping is the correct method in this context. I don't seem to be able to just run a function from an R package to do this, so I want to be sure my understanding is correct here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrapping is recommended because the product of two regression coefficients (mediated effect) is not normally distributed. Therefore, asymmetric confidence intervals derived from (bias-corrected) bootstrapping are often used to test indirect effects. See

MacKinnon, D. P., Lockwood, C. M., & Williams, J. (2004). Confidence limits for the indirect effect: Distribution of the product and resampling methods. *Multivariate Behavioral Research, 39*(1), 99-128.

You could run your model via path analysis using the lavaan package in R or Mplus. Both lavaan and Mplus allow you to obtain bias-corrected bootstrap CIs. See

https://groups.google.com/g/lavaan/c/oB0CY0ruaLA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-uO4VnvkoM

Comment: Thanks Christian, this is an awesome answer. I appreciate you pointing out the lavaan package, I was looking for R packages online but for some reason was under the impression that you could only have a single covariate working through the mediator (that seems to be the case in e.g., the mediation package), so I didn't look further into it. I'll give it a try.