# How to interpret my SEM output in R (1x IV; 2x Mediators; 2x DV)

Tags: r, regression, structural-equation-modeling

I am having problems with the interpretation of my SEM results.
My SEM consists of 1 IV (basic psychological need satisfaction [bpns]), 2 DV (Burnout [MBIscore] & Job Satisfaction [JobSat]) and 2 mediators (Emotional Intelligence [EQ] & Affect Ratio [corAffectRatio]).
I constructed my model with the following code:
[SEM Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tEMF.png)

```
# Define the SEM model with mediation
model <- '
  # Latent variables
    f1 =~ MBIscore
    f2 =~ JobSat
    
    med1 =~ corAffectRatio
    med2 =~ EQ

  # Structural model
    f1 ~ b*bpns + c1*med1 + c2*med2
    f2 ~ a*bpns + d1*med1 + d2*med2

  # Add undirected correlations
     med2 ~~ med1
     f2 ~~ f1

  # Mediation paths
    med1 ~ e*bpns
    med2 ~ f*bpns

  # Indirect effects (mediation effects)
    medEQ_MBI := b*f
    medEQ_JS := a*f
    medAR_MBI := b*e
    medAR_JS := a*e
'

# Fit the SEM model
fit <- sem(model = model, data = SEM_Daten, estimator = "MLM", bootstrap = 5000)

# Summarize the results
summary(fit, standardized = TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE, rsquare = TRUE)
```

[Model fit parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94aIB.png)
[Interpretation parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD7d7.png)

```
lavaan 0.6.16 ended normally after 37 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                        14

  Number of observations                            31

Model Test User Model:
                                              Standard      Scaled
  Test Statistic                                 0.000       0.000
  Degrees of freedom                                 0           0

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                                59.141      84.875
  Degrees of freedom                                10          10
  P-value                                        0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  0.697

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    1.000       1.000
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       1.000       1.000
                                                                  
  Robust Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                            NA
  Robust Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                               NA

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

  Loglikelihood user model (H0)                -44.211     -44.211
  Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)        -44.211     -44.211
                                                                  
  Akaike (AIC)                                 116.423     116.423
  Bayesian (BIC)                               136.499     136.499
  Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (SABIC)         92.881      92.881

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.000          NA
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.000          NA
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.000          NA
  P-value H_0: RMSEA <= 0.050                       NA          NA
  P-value H_0: RMSEA >= 0.080                       NA          NA
                                                                  
  Robust RMSEA                                               0.000
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower                     0.000
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper                     0.000
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA <= 0.050                            NA
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA >= 0.080                            NA

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.000       0.000

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                           Robust.sem
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  f1 =~                                                                 
    MBIscore          1.000                               0.538    1.000
  f2 =~                                                                 
    JobSat            1.000                               0.633    1.000
  med1 =~                                                               
    corAffectRatio    1.000                               0.440    1.000
  med2 =~                                                               
    EQ                1.000                               0.247    1.000

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  f1 ~                                                                  
    bpns       (b)   -0.378    0.153   -2.473    0.013   -0.702   -0.318
    med1      (c1)   -0.599    0.257   -2.332    0.020   -0.490   -0.490
    med2      (c2)    0.703    0.190    3.707    0.000    0.322    0.322
  f2 ~                                                                  
    bpns       (a)    0.744    0.221    3.359    0.001    1.175    0.532
    med1      (d1)    0.369    0.279    1.325    0.185    0.257    0.257
    med2      (d2)    0.134    0.282    0.474    0.636    0.052    0.052
  med1 ~                                                                
    bpns       (e)    0.538    0.117    4.614    0.000    1.222    0.553
  med2 ~                                                                
    bpns       (f)    0.151    0.100    1.513    0.130    0.610    0.276

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
 .med1 ~~                                                               
   .med2              0.011    0.013    0.829    0.407    0.129    0.129
 .f1 ~~                                                                 
   .f2                0.037    0.035    1.049    0.294    0.219    0.219

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .MBIscore          0.000                               0.000    0.000
   .JobSat            0.000                               0.000    0.000
   .corAffectRatio    0.000                               0.000    0.000
   .EQ                0.000                               0.000    0.000
   .f1                0.151    0.038    4.016    0.000    0.521    0.521
   .f2                0.190    0.051    3.741    0.000    0.475    0.475
   .med1              0.135    0.030    4.491    0.000    0.694    0.694
   .med2              0.056    0.016    3.535    0.000    0.924    0.924

R-Square:
                   Estimate
    MBIscore          1.000
    JobSat            1.000
    corAffectRatio    1.000
    EQ                1.000
    f1                0.479
    f2                0.525
    med1              0.306
    med2              0.076

Defined Parameters:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
    medEQ_MBI        -0.057    0.046   -1.245    0.213   -0.428   -0.088
    medEQ_JS          0.112    0.083    1.345    0.179    0.717    0.147
    medAR_MBI        -0.203    0.096   -2.120    0.034   -0.858   -0.176
    medAR_JS          0.400    0.163    2.452    0.014    1.435    0.294`
```

So how to I interpret this? Everything in the regression with Burnout (f1) is significant, but then in the mediation path only Affect Ratio (0.034) is significant and seems to be a significant mediator, EQ (0.213) is not. And for Job Satisfaction it's the same.
Also for Job Satisfaction the regressions for EQ (0.636) and corAffectRatio (0.185) are not significant in the first place - can I still use them?
And where in this output do I see the effect that the mediators have on my DVs?

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation seems correct. However, typically, we would use (asymmetric) confidence intervals (CIs) based on bias-corrected (bc) bootstrapping to test the indirect (mediated) effects because the product of coefficients is not normally distributed and the bc-bootstrap CIs provide greater statistical power. See:

[How to perform inference in a simple mediation analysis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/636737/how-to-perform-inference-in-a-simple-mediation-analysis)

The (direct) effects of the mediators on the DVs are given by the paths that you labeled as c1, c2, d1, and d2.

You wrote: "Also for Job Satisfaction the regressions for EQ (0.636) and corAffectRatio (0.185) are not significant in the first place - can I still use them?"

It depends on what you mean by "can I still use them." A statistical result is what it is--whether it is statistically significant or not. So it should be reported, even if it is not in line with your hypotheses.